# Strange characters in array

Tags: java, scramble

When do test of `scramble()` method it actually returns something like this:

```
public class Scramble_game {    
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      System.out.println("START");
      Word name = new Word("iskander");
      System.out.println(name.getWord() + "  " + name.getScrambleWord());
   }
}
```

my output is always like this:

> START
>       [C@57f530d8  [C@2259e205

```
public class Word 
{
   char[] word;
   char[] scrambleWord;
   boolean[] letters;
   boolean correct;

   public Word(String wordName)
   {
      this.word = wordName.toCharArray();
      this.letters = new boolean[wordName.length()];
      this.correct = false;        
      this.scrambleWord = this.scramble();
   }

   public char[] getScrambleWord(){return this.scrambleWord;}
   public char[] getWord(){return this.word;}

   public int getIndex()
   {
      Random rnd = new Random();
      int i = rnd.nextInt(this.word.length);
      if(this.letters[i] == true)
      {
         return getIndex();
      }
      this.letters[i] = true;
      return i;
   }

   public char[] scramble()
   {
      char[] temp = new char[this.word.length];
      for(int i = 0; i < this.word.length; i++)
      {
         char tempChar = word[this.getIndex()];
         temp[i] = tempChar;
      }
      return temp;
   }
}
```

As I understood this strange words are the addresses of objects?
I might be wrong, can you explain me what are these strange letters and where is my code problem.

Comment: I don't know nothing about Java, but I think you're supposed to use `StringBuilder` when creating a string like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print a `char[]` as a String, you need to manually convert it, like so:

```
public String getWord() { return new String(this.word); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to print a Java object, the virtual machine tries to invoke a `toString()` method of this object. Since Word hasn't overriden a `toString()` method, java will invoke the default `toString()` imlementation of `Object` class, which is:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

This method basically print the object "adress". If you want to print something more user friendly you would need to override a toString method (if it's your class) or manually extract what you are interested in.

Comment: This is not wrong, but not helpful here, because OP doesn't print a `Word` instance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert char[] to String ***String.valueOf***(charArray)
have to be used instead of ***toString()*** method, which will return the object's address as it was previously mentioned.

```
char[] customCharArray = {'m','y',' ','a','r','r','a','y'};
String requiredString = String.valueOf(customCharArray);
System.out.println(requiredString);

Output: my array
```